# bash + how to avoid specific messages in the log file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell-script

when I run the bash script on my Linux machine we get the following errors in my log ,

note - we set in the script:

```
exec > $log 2>&1 ,  (  in order to send all standard error/output to $log )
```

the errors messages:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

in order to filter this errors messages we try to set in the bash script that:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

**but without help**

after digging we found that  happened in some case for example when we perform ssh to remote machine and runs commands on remote machine VIA ssh

in order to avoid that we set TERM=xterm  in the bash script as the following:

```
ssh user@$remote_machine "TERM=xterm  /tmp/script.sh"
```

but it’s very not elegant solution and because my script use a lot of ssh and curl command then it’s not practical solution to set this on each SSH or curl etc

**so my big question is**

how to filter the message – **tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified** ?

so we not get these ugly message in my **$log** file

Comment: what happens if you run ssh with -t option to force assigning a terminal event for non interactive session?

Comment: Does https://serverfault.com/questions/75896/is-there-any-way-to-exclude-specific-entries-from-linux-log-files help?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try to filter it before passing to the log ? Like this maybe ?

```
exec 2>&1 | egrep -v "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified" > $log
```

---

Upon reflection, this does not work with exec. Maybe it is better to define this outside the script, i.e. with a wrapper script.

See if this works:

Comment out the exec and log statement from your script, like this

```
#exec > $log 2>&1
```

and execute the script with

```
/path/to/script.sh 2>&1 | egrep -v "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified" > /path/to/log
```

Comment: this stay the log file empty in spite script running

Comment: I just realized that this won't work with exec. maybe try and place this at the end of your script : sed -i '/tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified/d' $log

Comment: not so good because log appears online on the application window also

Comment: since you seem to have filter out the messages before they are written to the log file, I've added a different method.